# populate dynamic drop list with php mysql ajax jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

i need to create three dynamic drop list that the second is based on the selection of the first and the third is based on the selection of the second but i get a problem that the second and the third display the default value without any option to  choose another values

can anyone help me???

## dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "****";
$password = "****";
$db = "lam_el_chamel_db";
?>
```

## select.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#governorate").change(function(){
            $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#district").html(data);
            });
        });
        $("select#district option:selected").change(function(){
         id = $(this).val(); 
         $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){
         $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
         $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");

         $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
         $("select#village").html(data);
        });
        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var cat = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
            var type = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
            var vil = $("select#village option:selected").attr('value');
            if(cat>0 && type>0 && vil>0)
            {
                var result = $("select#district option:selected").html();
                $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form id="select_form">
            Choose a governorate:<br />
            <select id="governorate" name = 'governorate'>

            <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>


            </select>
            <br /><br />

           choose a district:<br />
            <select id="district">
                <option value="0">choose...</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
             choose a village:<br />
            <select id="village">
                <option value="0">choose...</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## select_class.php

```
<?php 
 class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()

        {
           $this->DbConnect();
        }
    protected function DbConnect()
   {
    include "dbconfig.php";
    $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
    return TRUE;
   }  

    public function ShowGovernorate()
    {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM governorate";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $governorate = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $governorate .= '<option value="' . $row['governorate_id'] . '">' . $row['governorate_name'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $governorate;

    }
    public function ShowDistrict()
   {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM districts WHERE governorate_id=$_POST[id]";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
    var_dump($res);
    $district = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
        $district .= '<option value="' . $row['district_id'] . '">' . $row['district_name'] . '</option>';
      }
    return $district;
   }

   public function ShowVillage()
   {
    $sql = "SELECT village_id, village_name FROM village WHERE district_id=$_POST[id]";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
    $village = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       {
         $village .='<option value="' .$row['village_id'] . '">' . $row['village_name'] . '</option>';
       }
       return $village;
   }


}   
$opt = new SelectList(); 


?>
```

## select_district.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowDistrict();
?>
```

## select_village.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowVillage();
?>
```

Comment: yes sir because i did not get any answer and i need a help plz if you can help me i will appreciate that

Comment: Check if your database SELECT is returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("select#district option:selected").change(function(){
     id = $(this).val(); 
     $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){
     $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
     $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");

     $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("select#village").html(data);
    });
```

try to

```
$("select#district").change(function(){ 
id = $(this).val(); 
     $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
     $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");
     $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){


     $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("select#village").html(data);
    });
```

Comment: @ joe lee this solution did not work

Comment: @ i had the error in the field name of the village table   so the didstrict populate successfully but the village still not populate

Comment: $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){ .. alert(data) what u see?

Answer (score 0):

I have found two mistakes in code which have tou pasted.

1. missing things in code:

   ```
       $("select#district option:selected").change(function(){
           id = $(this).val(); 
           $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){
               $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
               $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");

               $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
               $("select#village").html(data);
           }); }); //You have missed this one
   ```
2. In the code aboove you have add something which isn't good change this one:

   $("select#district option:selected").change(function(){

to this:

```
$("select#district").change(function(){
```